# Increase performance of box-shadow

Tags: jquery, performance, css

I think it's quite likely the answer is no, but someone might know something I don't.

I've got an image gallery with sorting buttons that, when clicked, sorted the gallery in an animated style using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). Each image has a nice `box-shadow` around it, but the animation is sluggish and jerky, due to having to render the shadow all the time.

My question is this: Is there a way to speed up box shadow without changing the blur radius, etc?

Comment: Is it slow in only one browser, or is it equally slow in all browsers?

Comment: It's worst in Opera where I'm getting what looks like ~10-15FPS (very laggy), then comes Firefox with only a slight jumpiness. Chrome renders it perfectly and smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there's no way to speed it up.

Have you considered toggling off the `box-shadow` while the animation is running?

Does the `box-shadow` use an `rgba` colour with transparency? *Maybe* it would be faster without transparency.

Comment: It just uses a bog standard `#aabbcc` colour code. I could turn the shadow off when animating, but I've chosen to just leave the shadow out for browsers that aren't Chrome, seeing as it has the fastest animation by far.